# How can i skip image tab in string using AngularJS filter?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to skip img tab when i do filter.
I already tested but it is not ok.
It still filter img or src value.
So pls help me.

Here is my code

Filter

```
app.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (text, phrase) {
        if (phrase) {
            var matches = String(text).match(/<img.*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:<\/img>)?/m);
            var img_src = (matches && matches.length && matches[0]) ? matches[0] : '';
            text = text.replace(img_src, "#");

            text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'ig'),
                '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
            text = text.replace("#", img_src);
        }
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
})
```

Controller

```
$scope.imgList = [];
        imgList.push('<img src="image1.jpg">');
        imgList.push('<img src="image2.jpg">');
        imgList.push('Using <img src="image1.jpg">“this” instead of “scope” <img src="image3.jpg"/> <p>Post Description <img src="image4.jpg"/></p>');
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="searchText" type="text">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="img in imgList">
        <p ng-bind-html="img | highlight:searchText"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
Filter be like this:

```
app.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (text, phrase) {
        if (text && phrase) {
            var matches = String(text).match(/<img.*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:<\/img>)?/g);
            if(matches && matches.length != 0){
                for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                    text = text.replace(matches[i], "#_#" + i);
                }
            }

            text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'ig'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
            if(matches && matches.length != 0){
                for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                    text = text.replace("#_#" + i, matches[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
})
```